# How are colourized season 1 episodes available on Netflix?

Tags: netflix, bewitched-tv

I've been watching Bewitched on Netflix, and I noticed that two episodes in season 1 are in colour, while the rest of the episodes in the season are in black and white.

I read that the show switched to colour in season 3, so how are these two season 1 episodes offered in colour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bewitched#DVD_releases):

> Beginning in 2005, Sony Pictures Home Entertainment released all eight seasons of Bewitched. In regions 1 and 4, seasons 1 and 2 were each released in two versions—one as originally broadcast in black-and-white, and one colorized. Only the colorized editions were released in regions 2 and 4.